# Unit Tests not updating states when setState is called in a callback

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jasmine, enzyme

I'm testing a simple modal component that when you click a button to open it, a request is sent where there are two callbacks (success, error). When the success callback is called 3 states are changed:

```
function sucessGet(data) {
    console.log('sucessGet');
    setIsLoaded(true);
    setBody(true);
    setVisible(true);
  }
```

The only state that I'm testing is `visible` where I send as an prop to my modal.

In my test:

```
fit('Expect isOpen prop from AppModal to be true when successGet is called', () => {
    component = mount(<ReportModal data={dataNotReported} viewIndex={1} />);
    let AppModal = component.find('AppModal');

    console.log('Before Props', AppModal.prop('isOpen'));
    component.find('MdReportProblem').simulate('click');
    console.log('After Props', AppModal.prop('isOpen'));
  });
```

It calls the `onClick` function:

```
onClick={() => {
          reported ? '' : GetFraud();
        }}
```

That calls `GetFraud`:

```
function GetFraud() {
    console.log('getfraud');
    setIsLoaded(false);
    TransactionalAnalysisStore.GetFraudReport(eventId, sucessGet, errorGet);
  }
```

And when all that is done my logs are like this:

```
LOG: 'visible', false
LOG: 'visible', false
LOG: 'Before Props', false
LOG: 'getfraud'
LOG: 'visible', false
LOG: 'After Props', false
LOG: 'sucessGet'
```

After `successGet` is called, there is no update to my `state`(visible), obviously failing the test.
Can anyone give a light of hope and tell me why this is not updating the state?

Answer (score 1):

Your state is not updating becasue of useState hooks works as a asyncronously.
Means it takes take some time for update , use async await for it hope it will work.
the beasr way to update state in useEffect() hook, just update your state on useEfect.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, but, the real problem was that when calling a test function, you can define a parameter callback usually named as `done`, and since my success callback function was asynchronous the test didn't wait for the life cycle to complete.
But just by adding a 
`setTimeout(()=>{
  done()
},500)`
It worked.

Comment: any documentation on the above?